Error 500 in Flutter but In Postman Works
Future<List<RouteData>> getRouteDetail({
    required String imei,
    required String deviceId,
    required String deviceType,
    required String phoneType,
    required String phoneBrand,
    required String phoneOS,
    required double latitude,
    required double longitude,
    required String appVersion,
    required String timestamp,
    required String activation,
    required String signature,
    required String route, // Passing the route
  }) async {
    const String url = Global.BASE_API + Global.FIND_SCHEDULE_TRANSPORT;

    try {
      // Create the JSON data
      final Map<String, dynamic> requestData = {
        'route': route, // The correct JSON format
      };

      print("Sending data: ${jsonEncode(requestData)}");

      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(url),
        body: jsonEncode(
            requestData), // Ensure the data is properly encoded as JSON
        headers: {
          'X-IMEI': imei,
          'X-DEVICE-ID': deviceId,
          'X-DEVICE-TYPE': deviceType,
          'X-PHONE-TYPE': phoneType,
          'X-PHONE-BRAND': phoneBrand,
          'X-PHONE-OS': phoneOS,
          'X-LATITUDE': latitude.toString(),
          'X-LONGITUDE': longitude.toString(),
          'X-APP-VERSION': appVersion,
          'X-API-ACTIVATION-CODE': activation,
          'X-API-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
          'X-API-SIGNATURE': signature,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Correct Content-Type for JSON
        },
      );

      print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final List<dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body)['data'];
        return responseData.map((json) => RouteData.fromJson(json)).toList();
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load bus routes: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to load bus routes: $e');
    }
  }

The below is the error
Reloaded 1 of 2802 libraries in 2,964ms (compile: 75 ms, reload: 1120 ms, reassemble: 1660 ms).
I/flutter (13061): Headers:
I/flutter (13061): X-IMEI: 1dedbb40-5ba7-11ef-b2cd-adcc39c0def4
I/flutter (13061): X-DEVICE-ID: c50807a8-f410-4caa-8724-658a12c54217
I/flutter (13061): X-DEVICE-TYPE: Android
I/flutter (13061): X-PHONE-TYPE: 2201117TY
I/flutter (13061): X-PHONE-BRAND: Redmi
I/flutter (13061): X-PHONE-OS: Android 13
I/flutter (13061): X-LATITUDE: -6.2473951
I/flutter (13061): X-LONGITUDE: 106.7971141
I/flutter (13061): X-APP-VERSION: 1.0.0
I/flutter (13061): X-API-ACTIVATION-CODE: VTJGc2RHVmtYMThkcVNJc20vM3NsQVdDeGxqV01mdlkyNHFjaTJlTmR1ZW1iNCtzdHFPU29TMzFGYkw3djlMSU5qT2R1WmFmR0JnVEI2WHJSUXZrYVFQV2JqM29ZekF4TThGZVlHZ0dTRVE4b3YvZTNubG55bGtCTnRpVUNGQThzWmpIWTV6cjZUbDBqMkJKR3VuZmZTT0NLSUsvZDkxS0RyZ3hKRUg5dThVPQ==
I/flutter (13061): X-API-TIMESTAMP: 2024-08-17T05:25:54+00:00
I/flutter (13061): X-API-SIGNATURE: wWNE3wGV9exPHUMH7mPBayiASXmcAk6xZXYWeOMPIxgFp0RnKJ8v7O+od4+IKcVYdnCahbnE67v0CLwhAk9cyA==
I/flutter (13061): Sending data: {"route":"BEKASI"}
I/flutter (13061): Response status: 500
[log] Error fetching routes: Exception: Failed to load bus routes: Exception: Failed to load bus routes: Internal Server Error
I/flutter (13061): Response body: {"status":"500","message":"Internal Server Error [Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)\n at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 1]]","data":null,"error":"Internal Server Error [Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)\n at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 1]]","timestamp":1723872356036}

I was try in plain/text and application/json in dio and http and still error why is it?

I wonder if you're accidentally double-encoding your body.  Try removing your jsonEncode.  http.post automatically encodes the body if the content type is proper, as I recall.

Try to replace 'Content-Type': 'application/json' with 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'.

pass Api key in controller
first store, load and retrive api key in login screen using SharedPreferences
then use FlutterSecureStorage() package to load api key when ever user loged in
